# git smudge/clean filters to only act on text (not binary) files

Tags: git, filter

While writing git filters for smudge & clean, I want to make sure that the filters only act on text files and not binary ones (images and the like).

Is there a way for git to tell me whether it thinks
the file is binary or not?  I could test the file myself, but I am not confident that I will always get the same result as git.

Comment: I have found this: 
`git grep -I --name-only -e "" --  <file_name>`
Which outputs file_name for text files and nil on binaries.
But there is a problem in that I don't know how to get access to the file name of the file that is being filtered.

Comment: Another SO question gave me: `clean = git-p4-filter --clean %f` so `%f` is where the file name would be passed.

Answer (score 1):

One cheap way is to use file extension:

If you declare your smudge/clean script in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), you can associate it to a certain list/group of files, based on a filename pattern.

> you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out

Plus, in that [same `.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), you can tell git what files are binaries or not.

In short, it is a declarative process.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to keep track of which files are binary.  I want git to apply the filters on all (non-binary) files, where it makes the determination of text vs. binary.